# how to link css file to aspx in azure host?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-roles

I have asp.net app that I am trying to upload to azure host.
first I have try to link in the traditional way with Css folder and link to it

```
<link href="http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/css/style.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

NOT WORKING

**then i create blob and reference to it :**

```
<link href="http://mysite.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/style.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

NOT WORKING

now I dont get error but nothing happend to the styling (after empty my cache and restart the site)
I am not using master pages in my site just normal asp.net page.
i saw in some place that they are doing it with master page but there is other way to do it without master page.

Thanks.

Comment: If you put the url for the css in a browser, does it download?  If not, you may need to make sure your blob is available to the public.

Comment: yes,it download it.maybe it is the problem becuase if you put other site css link it show me the css file on insude the browser(chrome ) but here it download the file why is this different.